# Create a JSON-LD for a Chrome Web Store extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, json-ld

How would one go about generating a JSON-LD block for a Chrome Web Store extension? The source is a regular website and the linked extension should be found on the store. The example found at https://schema.org/SoftwareApplication doesn't seem to describe properly a Web Store extension

```json
    {
      "@context": "https://schema.org",
      "@type": "Restaurant",
      "name": "Tartine Bakery",
      "potentialAction": {
        "@type": "ViewAction",
        "target": [
          "http://www.urbanspoon.com/r/6/92204",
          {
            "@type": "EntryPoint",
            "urlTemplate": "http://api.urbanspoon.com/r/6/92204",
            "contentType": "application/json+ld"
          },
          "android-app://com.urbanspoon/http/www.urbanspoon.com/r/6/92204",
          {
            "@type": "EntryPoint",
            "urlTemplate": "urbanspoon://r/6/92204",
            "actionApplication": {
              "@type": "SoftwareApplication",
              "@id": "284708449",
              "name": "Urbanspoon iPhone & iPad App",
              "operatingSystem": "iOS"
            }
          },
          {
            "@type": "EntryPoint",
            "urlTemplate": "urbanspoon://r/6/92204",
            "actionApplication": {
              "@type": "SoftwareApplication",
              "@id": "5b23b738-bb64-4829-9296-5bcb59bb0d2d",
              "name": "Windows Phone App",
              "operatingSystem": "Windows Phone 8"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```